# GNU Make: Multiple output rule with .INTERMEDIATE target cannot be combined with generated included makefile

Tags: gnu-make

In my project, I have an action that produces several output files simultaneously. One of them contains rules like the compile target.

Here is a small example makefile of what I would  like to run.

```
SHELL = cmd.exe
rules_InputFiles = makefile
rules_OutputFiles = exec\rules.mk exec\other.mk

$(rules_OutputFiles): exec\rules.temp

.INTERMEDIATE: exec\rules.temp
exec\rules.temp: $(rules_InputFiles)
    $(info == generating rules.mk and rules2.mk (due to $?)  ==)
    if not exist exec mkdir exec
    @echo compile: >exec\rules.mk
    # precede the second @echo with a tab character
    @echo <tab>@echo !!!! compiling !!! >>exec\rules.mk
    @echo compile2: >exec\other.mk
    # precede the second @echo with a tab character
    @echo <tab>@echo !!!! compiling2 !!! >>exec\other.mk    

-include exec\rules.mk
```

Invoking `make compile` for this makefile results in the make error message:

```
*** No rule to make target 'compile'.  Stop.
```

The second invocation runs normal with the output `!!!! compiling !!!` 
I would like run make only once, since this should run on a build server without interaction.

This makefile is a combination of the rules in [constructed included makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-include-files/) and the generation of multiple targets with an intermediate target.

My question is: can this makefile be modified to achieve my goals?

I tried several workarounds. One of them is to omit the intermediate target and use rules.mk as a marker file. This corresponds to the article of mad-scientists, but doesn't include the necessary dependencies.

Restating the rule as `$(rules_OutputFiles): $(rules_InputFiles)`, leads to the recipe executing twice, which is not desired.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't to do with *INTERMEDIATE*, it's because you are lying to *make*.

In its initial are-the-makefiles-up-to-date stage,
*make* sees that it has to update `exec/rules.mk`.
Before doing that, it has to update `exec/rules.temp`.

- `exec/rules.temp` does not exist

  - Runs the recipe for `exec/rules.temp`
- Recipe for `exec/rules.mk` does not exist

  - *make* does nothing, and sadly does not notice that this file was created magically as a side effect of the recipe for `exec/rules.temp`

To prove this is a case, just add a recipe for `exec/rules.mk`.
Anything will do.
The simplest possible thing is:

```
exec/rules.mk: ;
```

With this simple addition,
*make* will now check to see if `exec/rules.mk` has actually been updated since it last read (or failed to read) it.
Job done.
(Apart from leaving your makefile with a dodgy style that is. Moral: Your life will be much *much* happier if you do not lie to *make*.)